# Как вывести длину массива в Blaze

Tags: meteor

Использую Метеор и Blazejs
Я возвращаю хелпером массив с данными. Один из элементов является массивом и в шаблоне мне нужно вывести не значения этой переменной, а только длину массива.
Подскажите, как можно сделать?

Пример:

```
<template name="lists">
  {{#each}}
    {{>list}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.lists.helper({
  lists() {
    return [a, b, [c,d,e]]
  }
})

<template name="list">
  <div class="content">
    <div>{{a}}</div>
    <div>{{b}}</div>
    <div>{{variable.length}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: А  `array.length` вывести не пробовали? Давно blaze не использовался.

Comment: ни length, ни count не срабатывают. при работе с массивом нашел вывод текущего индекса элемента через @index, но с длиной так и не ясно. Странно, конечно, что такой простой вопрос, а никакая документация Blaze не говорит об этом.

Comment: Ну хотя бы код покажите, а то не понятно как-то

Comment: Добавил пример с кодом в описание вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Решить вопрос можно при помощи хелпера для шаблона list

```
Template.list.helpers({
  qty(variable) {
    return variable.length
  }
})

<template name="list">
  <div class="content">
    <div>{{a}}</div>
    <div>{{b}}</div>
    <div>{{qty variable}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Смысл манипуляции в передаче переменной в хелпер, там вычисляем длину массива и возвращаем, как значение переменной